# How to center pattern fill in FabircJs?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

How do I center the pattern fill of a FabricJS object? It seems the pattern is always oriented to top/left. I have tried setting originX and OriginY to 'center' on the pattern, the filled object, the canvas, nothing seems to help. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

Patterns use offsets, and not origins. So, to simulate centering a pattern, consider the following requirements:

1. The center is at half-width of the object.
2. To be centered, the pattern object must be at the center point at half it's width.

```
pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
    source: function () {[...]},
    repeat: 'repeat',
    offsetX: [objectwidth/2] - [patternwidth/2],
    offsetY: [objectheight/2] - [patternheight/2]
});
```

That did it! If you changed the scale on either of the items, you will need to compensate for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

In [Pattern Example](http://fabricjs.com/dynamic-patterns/) of Fabric.js there are only `int` values used as OriginX/Y.

Try to set it by number, to the half of your image size.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I will try this. My patterns differ in that they are constructed from paths, instead of images. I would imagine they work in the same manner though.
Is the positioning relative to the pattern canvas, or the pattern image? I imagine the canvas size is the deciding factor, as that is used to create the pattern.

Comment: I finally got around to looking at this issue again. Unfortunately the pattern example doesn't user OriginX, but instead uses OffsetX/Y to move the pattern. Is there a way to manipulate the offset to compensate for the size of the patter, so as to always have it centered?